# JS Sapper + Bulma breakpoints in (S)CSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass, bulma, sapper

I'm trying to use Sapper with Bulma and (S)CSS.

My goal is to apply various paddings on "main" inside of src/routes/layout.html, with padding on desktop devicees, and without (or a smaller one) on mobile.

Using the predefined breakpoints or mixins doesn't work properly for me, as the following code raises an SCSS error :

EDIT: this is the svelte component:

```
<script>
    import 'bulma/css/bulma.css' 
    // or import 'bulma/bulma.sass' ???
</script>
<style type="text/scss">
main {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 56em;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5em;

  +desktop-only {
    padding: 2em;
  }
}
</style>
```

What's wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: The browser can't run scss, you have to compile it to css first

Comment: the error occured at compile time (svelte-preprocess) inside shell (npm run dev))

Comment: including css will prevent you from using the bulma mixins/functions. And importing the sass version, keep in mind that it's sass and not scss